# Globally available macOS app with efficient typo correction UX

Tags: writing, grammar

I often make typos. I would love to have software (on macOS) that runs everywhere, scanning my text, and lets me fix typos as fast as possible.

I am aware that there are some apps/system settings that already exist in this lane. However, I've found they all do either too much or too little.

macOS keyboard settings "Text Replacements": Useful for fixing typos common enough to be explicitly listed (e.g. "teh" -> "the"), but misses a lot. Also I don't want to fix it automatically as I type, I want to review it.
Grammarly. Tons of grammar suggestions that are annoying.
Ideally the software subtly underlines potential errors while I write. Then I can select some text, push a hotkey, and the corrected text is shown in a popup with the corrections highlighted. At this point I can either tab-cycle through individual corrections, accepting or rejecting them (keyboard-driven is a must here), or more often just quickly hit a key for "Accept all" and it replaces the entirety of the text. After this processing, potential errors that were marked but with the fix not accepted are no longer marked.

In order to catch typos and only typos (I do not want grammar suggestions), I imagine some form of AI will be needed-- simply flagging misspelled words is not enough (e.g. imagine a space and a trailing "s" are out of order: "dog sare great".

Does this sofware exist?

Comment: I use Grammarly. I  dont find it in the face fir grammar suggestions. English is fickle.  It has to analyse the grammar as well to find spelling errors.